# 2D pointer to act like 2D array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

In C, I am trying to declare a 2D array outside of any function so that it can be shared by the functions. I know in the single dimensional case you can do the following(and make it behave LIKE an array):-

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int *ptr;

int main(){
  int n=5;
  int i;

  ptr = malloc(n*sizeof(*ptr));
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    ptr[i] = i;
    printf("%i\n", ptr[i]);
  }
  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

I am wondering how this would work for the multidimensional case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of a single pointer, you just use a double pointer:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int **ptr;

int main() {
  int n = 5;
  int m = 10;
  int i, j;

  ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    ptr[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    for(j=0; j<m; j++) {
      ptr[i][j] = j;
      printf("%i\n", ptr[i][j]);
    } 
  }

  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    free(ptr[i]);
  }
  free(ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Things you should be wary of:

- Allocate each array seperately
- Free each array seperately, and the whole

Comment: @VisionIncision: If you like this answer, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: @Silox Done. Sorry, I thought I still had a little time to wait before I could.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it using two indices with `[]` operator then you will need to use a pointer to pointer to `int` and allocate each single inner 1D array:

```
int **ptr = malloc(R*sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0, i < R; ++i)
  ptr[i] = malloc(C*sizeof(int));

ptr[i][j] = 40;
```

But you can also directly create a single 1D array of `R*C` elements and then access it by calculating the correct index `ptr[R*i + j]` or `ptr[C*j + i]`.

Comment: Ah brilliant, I didn't realize it would be this simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you fix the second dimension you can basically use the same "trick":

```
double (*A)[42];
```

If the second dimension is to be dynamic, too, you'd have to declare it in function scope:

```
double (*B)[n];
```

as a pointer to VLA, variable length array, and then pass the pointer to array to functions as

```
void f(size_t m, double (*aB)[m]);
```

you'd allocate such a 2D array in one go

```
B = malloc(sizeof(double[m][n]));
```

and thus you ensure that your matrix is contiguously allocated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `double (*B)[m][n] = malloc(sizeof(double[m][n]));`?

Comment: @alk, this would be just one indirection more, a possibility. But then you'd always have to write things like `(*B)[i][j]` to refer to an element instead of `B[i][j]`. The declaration as I gave it just lets you use it as the user would expect.